# How to (1) get depth of execute-nesting and (2) interrupt the global command?

Tags: vimscript

From a sourced file I am running my vim script. The aim of the script is to run `:global`. I am searching for

```
\\%(pattern1.*/)\@<!pattern2
```

The patterns are variables, so I use `execute`; for the work to be done, I use a second nested level of execute.

It turns out that within the `execute` I must use `|`, not newlines, to separate commands.

```
execute ' g#' . WE_pattern1 .  ' ' . WE_patter2 . '#execute " try |  ...work | to | be | done... | catch ... | endtry | " '
```

1. How can I get the depth of `execute`-nesting?
2. How can I `:finish` the script under some condition? `:finish` always gives the error message `E168: only in sourced ...`.
3. I catch `CTRL-C` interrupts, but after some processing how can I write that `CTRL-C` will be executed?

Answer (score 1):

1. There's simply no need for the second execute (and so neither for nested double-quotes) here.
2. You can re-throw exception at any point (`:h :throw`). Of course, it'll become "user-defined", not "Vim:Interrupt". But that should not matter.